# Ext.js - Format TimeStamp into yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss[.fffffffff]

Tags: javascript, extjs, timestamp

I have a timestamp value:

```
var timestamp = 1469088703280;
```

I have tried this to convert timestamp into format `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss[.fffffffff]`.

```
var timestampDate = new Date(timestamp * 1000);
Ext.Date.format(timestampDate ,'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')
```

However, my method produces value:

> 52525252-TemTem-2727 1414:0707:4444

Any ideas on how to achieve the required format?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see you have also asked for decimal fraction of seconds for which you can use below snippet.

```
var timestamp = new Date(new Date());
Ext.Date.format(timestamp ,'Y-m-d H:i:s.u');

"2016-07-28 14:03:26.711"
```

Refer Ext JS Docs more closely so that you can get any configuration you wish and you wont have to look elsewhere.

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2-classic/Ext.Date.html

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
Ext.Date.format(timestampDate ,'Y-m-d H:i:s')
```

- `Y` - A full numeric representation of a year, 4 digits.
- `m` - Numeric representation of a month, with leading zeros.
- `H` - 24-hour format of an hour with leading zeros.
- `i` - Minutes, with leading zeros
- `s` - Seconds, with leading zeros

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2-classic/Ext.Date.html

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own method:

```js
var timestamp = 1469088703280;

var timestampDate = new Date(timestamp);

console.log(timestampDate);

console.log(
  timestampDate.getDay() + '-' + 
  timestampDate.getMonth() + '-' + 
  timestampDate.getFullYear(), 
  timestampDate.getHours() + ':' + 
  timestampDate.getMinutes()
)
```